# Creating new distributions in scipy

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I'm trying to create a distribution based on some data I have, then draw randomly from that distribution. Here's what I have:

```
from scipy import stats
import numpy

def getDistribution(data):
    kernel = stats.gaussian_kde(data)
    class rv(stats.rv_continuous):
        def _cdf(self, x):
            return kernel.integrate_box_1d(-numpy.Inf, x)
    return rv()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # pretend this is real data
    data = numpy.concatenate((numpy.random.normal(2,5,100), numpy.random.normal(25,5,100)))
    d = getDistribution(data)

    print d.rvs(size=100) # this usually fails
```

I think this is doing what I want it to, but I frequently get an error (see below) when I try to do `d.rvs()`, and `d.rvs(100)` never works. Am I doing something wrong? Is there an easier or better way to do this? If it's a bug in scipy, is there some way to get around it?

Finally, is there more documentation on creating custom distributions somewhere? The best I've found is the scipy.stats.rv_continuous documentation, which is pretty spartan and contains no useful examples.

The traceback:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "testDistributions.py", line
>   19, in 
>       print d.rvs(size=100)   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/scipy-0.10.0-py2.6-linux-x86_64.egg/scipy/stats/distributions.py",
>   line 696, in rvs
>       vals = self._rvs(*args)   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/scipy-0.10.0-py2.6-linux-x86_64.egg/scipy/stats/distributions.py",
>   line 1193, in _rvs
>       Y = self._ppf(U,*args)   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/scipy-0.10.0-py2.6-linux-x86_64.egg/scipy/stats/distributions.py",
>   line 1212, in _ppf
>       return self.vecfunc(q,*args)   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/numpy-1.6.1-py2.6-linux-x86_64.egg/numpy/lib/function_base.py",
>   line 1862, in **call**
>       theout = self.thefunc(*newargs)   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/scipy-0.10.0-py2.6-linux-x86_64.egg/scipy/stats/distributions.py",
>   line 1158, in _ppf_single_call
>       return optimize.brentq(self._ppf_to_solve, self.xa, self.xb, args=(q,)+args, xtol=self.xtol)   File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/scipy-0.10.0-py2.6-linux-x86_64.egg/scipy/optimize/zeros.py",
>   line 366, in brentq
>       r = _zeros._brentq(f,a,b,xtol,maxiter,args,full_output,disp) ValueError: f(a) and f(b) must have different signs

**Edit**

For those curious, following the advice in the answer below, here's code that works:

```
from scipy import stats
import numpy

def getDistribution(data):
    kernel = stats.gaussian_kde(data)
    class rv(stats.rv_continuous):
        def _rvs(self, *x, **y):
            # don't ask me why it's using self._size 
            # nor why I have to cast to int
            return kernel.resample(int(self._size)) 
        def _cdf(self, x):
            return kernel.integrate_box_1d(-numpy.Inf, x)
        def _pdf(self, x):
            return kernel.evaluate(x)
    return rv(name='kdedist', xa=-200, xb=200)
```

Comment: So when we are doing the above and calling `randoms = getDistribution(Mydata)` and then `randoms = randoms.rvs(size=1000)` does it perform the three `def` inside the class? i.e calculating pdf, integrating it etc?

Comment: I do get my randoms to follow the data distribution, but I would like to smooth it so that it does not follow the data distribution exactly. I have been manually adjusting bandwidth in `kernel` to do that. For example, something like how we specify a PDF function and then use the PDF function to create randoms using Metropolis Hastings.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Specifically to your traceback:

rvs uses the inverse of the cdf, ppf, to create random numbers. Since you are not specifying ppf, it is calculated by a rootfinding algorithm, `brentq`. `brentq` uses lower and upper bounds on where it should search for the value at with the function is zero (find x such that cdf(x)=q, q is quantile).

The default for the limits, `xa` and `xb`, are too small in your example. The following works for me with scipy 0.9.0, `xa`, `xb` can be set when creating the function instance

```
def getDistribution(data):
    kernel = stats.gaussian_kde(data)
    class rv(stats.rv_continuous):
        def _cdf(self, x):
            return kernel.integrate_box_1d(-numpy.Inf, x)
    return rv(name='kdedist', xa=-200, xb=200)
```

There is currently a pull request for scipy to improve this, so in the next release `xa` and `xb` will be expanded automatically to avoid the `f(a) and f(b) must have different signs` exception.

There is not much documentation on this, the easiest is to follow some examples (and ask on the mailing list).

edit: addition

**pdf**: Since you have the density function also given by gaussian_kde, I would add the `_pdf` method, which will make some calculations more efficient.

edit2: addition

**rvs**: If you are interested in generating random numbers, then gaussian_kde has a resample method. Random Samples can be generated by sampling from the data and adding gaussian noise. So, this will be faster than the generic rvs using the ppf method. I would write a ._rvs method that just calls gaussian_kde's resample method.

**precomputing ppf**: I don't know of any general way to precompute the ppf. However, the way I thought of doing it (but never tried so far) is to precompute the ppf at many points and then use linear interpolation to approximate the ppf function.

edit3: about `_rvs` to answer Srivatsan's question in the comment

`_rvs` is the distribution specific method that is called by the public method `rvs`. `rvs` is a generic method that does some argument checking, adds location and scale, and sets the attribute `self._size` which is the size of the requested array of random variables, and then calls the distribution specific method `._rvs` or it's generic counterpart. The extra arguments in `._rvs` are shape parameters, but since there are none in this case, `*x` and `**y` are redundant and unused.

I don't know how well the `size` or shape of the `.rvs` method works in the multivariate case. These distributions are designed for univariate distributions, and might not fully work for the multivariate case, or might need some reshapes.

Comment: Awesome, thanks, this was very helpful. Is there some way to precompute the ppf from the cdf using the same methods that scipy is using, so that it's more efficient? I notice that _cdf() gets called a lot for each rv() call.

Comment: I added a few more comments on rvs and ppf. One more comment: gaussian_kde will not be very good in the tails if you have data with fat tails. When I thought about writing a similar distribution subclass, I would have tried to use pareto tails. I read a comment about this in a forum, and matlab has a Pareto Tail Distribution.

Comment: @user333700 I would like to know what does def _rvs(self, *x, **y) in the answer posted as the edit in the question do??